# Problem with nonlinear equation system

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

I need to calculate two coefficients: *k* and *n*. This involves solving two equations for *k* and *n*:

$$\frac{(8 \pi  d)}{\lambda }{kn}=\frac{\text{$\triangle $I}}{I}$$

$$\text{$\triangle $l}_2=\left\{\frac{\lambda }{2 \pi }\right\} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \left(n \sin \left(\frac{4 \pi  d n}{\lambda }\right)+k\right)}{\frac{4 \pi  d \left(n^2-1\right)}{\lambda }+\left(n^2+1\right) \cos \left(\frac{4 \pi  d n}{\lambda }\right)}\right)$$

I have all coefficients, except for *k* and *n*. Roughly:

$$k n=0.00730621$$

$$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 (k+n \sin (8.89655 n))}{8.89655 \left(n^2-1\right)+\left(n^2+1\right) \cos (8.89655 n)}\right) = 309.526$$
How should I tackle it?

I tried to solve this on *Mathematica*, but neither Solve, nor NSolve could manage it.

Thanks.